# Insertar valores con coma(,) desde un csv a mysql con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

tengo la siguiente duda, sucede que estoy insertando mediante PHP los registros obtenidos desde un csv

```
    while (($getData = fgetcsv($file, 20000, "\t")) !== false)
        {
           $sql = "INSERT into productos (categoria,subcategoria,nombre,marca,precio,disponibilidad,nro_parte,sku,atributos)
                       values ('" . $getData[0] . "','" . $getData[1] . "','" . $getData[2] . "','" . $getData[3] . "','" .  $getData[4] . "','" . $getData[5] . "','" . $getData[6] . "','" . $getData[7] . "','" . $getData[8] . "')";
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

                if (!isset($result)){}

}
```

Todos los registros se insertan bien, pero el tema es con el campo precio, actualmente para ver la información lo tengo en tipo de dato varchar, ya que si pruebo otro tipo de dato numérico me inserta en 0.

Los valores que llegan son de este tipo:

```
0,84 
1,1
1201,9
10
200
```

etc.
Como puedo hacer que se inserte con coma? tambien probe reemplazando la coma por punto, pero igual llega a 0 si por ejemplo cambio el tipo de dato a DECIMAL 10,2 u otro con decimal, ya que, luego necesito realizar cálculos con estos valores, por ejemplo multiplicarlos con otro tipo de dato numérico y me devuelve 0 la operación

Comment: has probado a insertar como numero, pero antes haciendo una conversion numerica del campo precio?

Comment: Revisa este tutorial creo te servirá de mucho(sorry no he usado PHP desde que lo aprendí) de todo lo que logro entender es lo que estas buscando https://www.cloudways.com/blog/import-export-csv-using-php-and-mysql/

Comment: @Jakala he probado pero cuando hago una conversion por ejemplo con floatval o (float) esto me devulve 0

Answer (score 0):

Una posible solucion seria hacer primero la conversion del campo a numerico:

```
$precio = floatval($getData[4]);
```

luego puedes hacer la inserción utilizando $precio, pero quitando las comas en el sql:

```
$sql = "INSERT into productos (categoria,subcategoria,nombre,marca,precio,disponibilidad,nro_parte,sku,atributos)
                   values ('" . $getData[0] . "','" . $getData[1] . "','" . $getData[2] . "','" . $getData[3] . "','" .  $precio . "','" . $getData[5] . "','" . $getData[6] . "','" . $getData[7] . "','" . $getData[8] . "')";
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, cuando hago eso me devuelve 0, hice un var_dump al campo getData y efectivamente es un string

Comment: Puedes mostrar el resultado de ese var_dump? Si se trata de números con el símbolo coma entonces son cadenas, y tendrás que cambiarlas por punto

Comment: asi es como me muestra los valores :string(9) "0,82" ,string(3) "4", string(13) "1201,9"

Comment: Tambien probe cambiando previamente el valor con:$precio = str_replace(',', '.', $getData[4]); pero tampoco me sirvio

Comment: Vas a tener que hacer una combinación de ambas. Revisa https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325363/converting-a-number-with-comma-as-decimal-point-to-float, puede que te solucione tu caso particular.